# Create databasebase with entity framework code first approach

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I do not want that my database is created when I insert a record. One reason is I do not want to create sample application, do an insert just to have a database...

I want that my database is created via the package manager console.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little unclear what you're asking, but I think you're trying to prevent the database from being created automatically from the application code.

The database is created on the first use of the DataContext. If you don't want the database to be created on the first use of the data context you can add `Database.SetInitializer<YourContextClassHere>(null);` to your Global.asax.cs file.

Then you could use the `Update-Database` cmdlet in Visual Studio to run the pending migrations including creating the database.

Comment: ah Update-Database creates the database ok never thought of that...Thanks.